# Python,mariaDB : How to use \G option?

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I want to use the \G option when query to execute in Python.

The \G option prints the query results vertically.

for example)

```
select * from exam\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
col_1: test2
col_2: test2
col_3: test2
*************************** 2. row ***************************
col_1: test3
col_2: test3
col_3: test3
*************************** 3. row ***************************
col_1: test4
col_2: test4
col_3: test4
```

So I used execute ("select * from exam \ G") to send the query.

but, this command was not executed.

```
db = pymysql.connect(
    host=localhost, port=3306,user=root,passwd=test,db=test,charset=utf8)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from exam\G")
data = cursor.fetchall()

for i in data:
    print i
```

that was result in error...

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the 
right syntax to use near '\\G' at line 1")
```

Can not use the \G option in pymysql?

Is there a way to produce the same result as \G?

thanks.

Comment: `\G` is a _feature_ of the mysql commandline tool, _not_ the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`\G` option is only for *displaying* results vertically](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/#displaying-query-results-vertically) in the prompt mode. It doesn't actually change what was returned.

> Queries can be displayed vertically by terminating the query with \G instead of a semicolon.

To repeat a similar effect in Python, remove the '\g' from the query and when you're looping over the results, do another loop over the columns.

```
data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data:
    for colval in row:
        print colval
```

And to get a column number with row, etc.

```
data = cursor.fetchall()

for rid, row in enumerate(data, start=1):
    print '*** row', rowid, '***'
    for colid, colval in enumerate(row, start=1):
        print colid, ':', colval
```

That would be easier to do with a [`MySQLCursorNamedTuple` cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursornamedtuple.html) which will do names+order for columns.

Comment: answer is late. Thank you!