# Using mysql-connector-python, how to insert a "complicated" (with delimiter instruction) trigger to MariaDB?

Tags: python, mariadb

I wish to create a trigger in MariaDB 5.5.68.

Base on [this official example](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-overview/#more-complex-triggers), I built this query:

```py
query = ("""
DELIMITER //
create trigger set_uuid_query
before insert on DLMNT.QUERY for each row
begin
    if new.id is null then
        set new.id = uuid() ;
    end if ;
end//
DELIMITER ;
""")
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
for e in cursor:
    print(e)
```

However, while this worked well with a MariaDB 5.5.64 via MySQL Workbench, this throws:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
create trigger set_uuid_query
before insert on DLMNT.QUERY for each' at line 1
```

I am afraid that this is not possible. While it is about MySQL, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053823/6213883) states that DELIMITER is a client side thing.

Also, based on the last line of [this doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/), I though "\G" could be used as a delimiter, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46947401/6213883) states something completely different (and it throws the exact same error anyway when I try it).

So, using this Python library, how can I make such a query ?

PS: the lib I am using is:
mysql-connector-python        8.0.27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not DELIMITER to create trigger, when using python (or any other) connector. DELIMITER is a *command line client's*  special trick. Command line client wishes to know when to send a potentially multiline input query to the server. Usually it can rely on semicolons at the end of string, but not in the case of "complex" statements, such as trigger and stored procedure.

Comment: And so, how can i create that trigger then ?

Comment: By removing DELIMITER //   AND //\nDELIMITER ; from your input?

Comment: But the query is not right then.

Comment: Why it is not right? You can switch on query log https://mariadb.com/kb/en/general-query-log/ , and look what queries the server gets. Server does not get any DELIMITER from clients

Comment: Mea culpa. I misunderstood what you said. Removing the delimiter statements and using semi colon in the trigger works fine.